# Hiding text if value is null in php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display list of information based on the user type. If the type is `M1` if will display these of input but if the type is `M2` it will display all the all value in database example

if type is `M1`

```
<?php
   if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);     
?>
 <h4>PROFILE</h4><br><br>
    <p>ID: <?php echo $row ['ID']; ?></p><br>
    <p>Business Type: <?php echo $row ['BusinessType']; ?></p><br>
 <?php if($row['BusinessType'] == "M1"): ?>
    <p>Name: <?php echo $row ['Name']; ?></p><br>
    <p>Address: <?php echo $row ['address']; ?></p><br>

<?php
    }
  else if($row ['BusinessType']=="M2") {
  ?>
    <p>Business Name: <?php echo $row ['business_name']; ?></p><br>
    <p>Business Owner: <?php echo $row ['business_owner']; ?></p><br>     
<?php } ?>
```

I was trying to achieve output where if the business type is `M1` it will will display the name of the address and if the type is `M2` if will display the company business name and the owner of the business. This is just my sample code.

with the coding above I get this output which is not displaying the name and the address.
[image]

Comment: If you add `print_r($row);` after the `mysqli_fetch_array` line, what does the output look like? The fields that you are trying to reference are a combination of CamelCase and underscore_case, and some have bussiness while others have business and even a bussines. Might be that this is all just because of a bunch of typos.

Comment: I got nothing displayed.

Comment: Is `$row` coming back as null?

Comment: sorry i did try again and put the `print_r($row);` I did get all the output for the id `Array ( [0] => 1 [ID] => 1 [1] => ` and the rest of the data

Comment: "the rest of the data" is what we'd need to see in order to tell you where your code is wrong.

Comment: thank you so much. I fixed it! Like you said its typo

Comment: @Greg Schmidt sir how you identify its a typos mistake.

Comment: Seemed unlikely that there were columns in the database called BusinessType and BussinessType and BussinesType (three different spellings) and business_name (different capitalization).

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out an opening curly brace in the if statement

Alter the "if" part:

```php
<?php if($row['BusinessType'] == "M1")
{ ?>
    <p>Name: <?php echo $row ['Name']; ?></p><br>
    <p>Address: <?php echo $row ['address']; ?></p><br>

<?php
}
...
```